# What is the effect of STARTUP IPI on Application Processor?

Tags: operating-system, intel, bios

I am right now trying to understand the booting procedure and how does the processors initializes. I have read the Multiprocessor Specification section B.4.2 but it is not clear to me what `INIT IPI` and `STARTUP IPI` does to the `BSP` and `AP`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general; `INIT IPI` is like a soft reset for the (logical) CPU, that puts it into a "wait for SIPI state". The Intel manuals have a table showing the default values of various registers after power on, after reset, and after `INIT IPI`.

The `Startup IPI` is a way to tell the CPU to start executing at a certain address (an address derived from the "vector field" of the `Startup IPI`) before a usable IDT can be set up. This also bumps the CPU out of the "wait for SIPI state". Some (most) CPUs will respond to a `Startup IPI` when they aren't in the "wait for SIPI state", but without a previous `INIT IPI` you can't expect the CPU to be in a known/safe state at the time.

All CPUs respond to `INIT IPI` and `Startup IPI` the same. The main difference between BSP and AP is during power on (BSP executes firmware while AP CPUs wait).